# install rpy2 on Windows7 64bit for Python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, r, rpy2

I am trying to build and install rpy2 Python Module. But got an error (see below).

I have R installed in `C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.0\` and `R.h` is in `C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.0\include`. How can I tell setup.py to find the R header in that directory?

Both Python and R were installed using official binary file for Windows 64bit.

Can someone contribute a rpy2 binary build for windows 64bit and Python2.7 64bit? Christoph Gohlke said for legal or technical reasons, rpy2 is not included in his [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Anyone else has a successful hit?

Thanks!

Given the following process:

```
$ python setup.py  build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext

returned an empty string. (5 times)
```

With this configuration for R as a library:

```
include_dirs: ()
libraries: ()
library_dirs: ('C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.0/bin/i386',)
extra_link_args: ()
 # OSX-specific (included in extra_link_args)
  framework_dirs: ()
  frameworks: ()
```

building 'rpy2.rinterface._rinterface' extension, using this command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c 
/nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DWin32=1 -DCSTACK_DEFNS=1 
-I.\rpy\rinterface -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC 
/Tc.\rpy\rinterface\_rinterface.c 
/Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\.\rpy\rinterface\_rinterface.obj
_rinterface.c
```

gives this error:

```
.\rpy\rinterface\_rinterface.c(61) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 
'R.h': No such file or directory
error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe"' 
failed with exit status 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a link to the rpy2 Windows binaries, all Python versions and x86/x64:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2

Comment: This does not include the rpy2 2.9.0 version

Comment: I got error about different ABI somehow although I selected download for correct C Python :(

Answer (score 2):

My experience (2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]):
- all binary installers
- apparently rpy2 has unspecified dependencies
- have numpy and scipy installed (win_amd64 binaries) with their unspecified dependencies

1. install R, install needed packages
2. install pywin32
3. "pip install singledispatch"
4. "pip install rpy2-2.5.6-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl"
5. update environment, e.g.
   os.environ['R_HOME'] = r'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3'
   os.environ['R_USER'] = r'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\rpy2'

Answer (score 1):

I am working through the same myself. The libraries etc. Located indicate that you are picking up the 32 bit version i386. Add "C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1\include" include directory may help force fix the problem. This is the farthest I have got:

```
building 'rpy2.rinterface._rinterface' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

With the MSVC express shell and R x64 and msys sh in path.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of these on my Windows 10 and got nowhere. When I did the `pip`, it said it was installed into the Anaconda version that I have been using for months, but when I tried an `import rpy`, it just gave an error.

Was going to give up, but then I slept on it a night and then I did the following from the command line:

- Deleted all my old Python instances including Anaconda
- Rebooted
- Reinstalled Anaconda (2.4.1 with Python version 2.7.11)
- Made sure python ran from the command line from any directory
- started my "mingw32" bash shell (the one that comes with `git`)
- Set my personal `R_HOME` environment variable to `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3`
- Downloaded `rpy2-2.7.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2 as suggested above.
- Changed the working directory to my user `Downloads` directory
- Installed it with `pip install rpy2-2.7.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`
- Started python and successfully imported and rn py2

Here is a screen capture of the final steps:

```
mwise@MWISE-OPTO ~/Downloads
$ pip install rpy2-2.7.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\users\mwise\downloads\rpy2-2.7.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in c:\users\mwise\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from rpy2==2.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): singledispatch in c:\users\mwise\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from rpy2==2.7.5
)
Installing collected packages: rpy2
Successfully installed rpy2-2.7.5

mwise@MWISE-OPTO ~/Downloads
$ python
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 14:10:42) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import rpy2
>>> import rpy2.robjects as robjects
>>> pi = robjects.r['pi']
>>> pi[0]
3.141592653589793
>>>
```

Hoping this will help someone down the line...

Answer (score -1):

This is because your R include library is not in your CPPFLAGS enviroment variable.
You should find the file R.h in your "C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.0\include".
In linux, you can add this to your .bashrc

```
export "$CPPFLAGS=-I/path-to-R/include $CPPFLAGS"
```

But i'm not familar to python and R in windows.
That's all I can help.