# ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed (error while running a package called ADEL wheat-- beginner)

Tags: python, dll, anaconda

I am trying to generate a canopy by using adel wheat but facing this error doing so.
[Error screenshot][1]

```py
from alinea.adel.astk_interface import AdelWheat
from alinea.astk.Weather import sample_weather


seq, weather = sample_weather()
wdata = weather.get_weather(seq)

adel = AdelWheat(nsect=2)

g = adel.setup_canopy(100)
adel.grow(g, wdata)
```

```
(adel) C:\Users\Personal\Desktop\OpenAlea research\adel\example>python test_AdelWheat.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_AdelWheat.py", line 1, in <module>
    from alinea.adel.astk_interface import AdelWheat
  File "C:\Users\Personal\Desktop\OpenAlea research\adel\src\alinea\adel\astk_interface.py", line 6, in <module>
    from alinea.adel.AdelR import setAdel, RunAdel, genGeoAxe, checkAxeDyn, getAxeT, \
  File "C:\Users\Personal\Desktop\OpenAlea research\adel\src\alinea\adel\AdelR.py", line 23, in <module>
    import rpy2.robjects as robj
  File "C:\Users\Personal\.conda\envs\adel\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File "C:\Users\Personal\.conda\envs\adel\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface\__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
    from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import (baseenv,
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

Comment: Can you share some information on your environment?

Comment: my environment contains a package from git repo :- https://github.com/openalea-incubator/adel. I get that 9 out 10 times but sometimes imports work fine

Comment: What other packages are in there? How did you install this one?

Comment: I installed this package by running "python setup.py install"

Comment: this environment  has majority of packages from https://github.com/openalea-incubator

Comment: @AMC did you get any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/openalea-incubator/adel#installation-with-conda) ?

Comment: @AMC yes I followed the same instructions >>> import rpy2 is working fine

Comment: Followed instructions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165123/install-rpy2-on-windows7-64bit-for-python-2-7) to install rpy2 which is causing the DLL error

Comment: followed instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165123/install-rpy2-on-windows7-64bit-for-python-2-7/29656592#29656592) to install rpy2

Comment: Which part(s) of the instructions? There are multiple steps.

Comment: @AMC issue is solved now replicating exact steps,

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?